# OnTriggerEnter being called on unexpected object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

Maybe I have a misunderstanding as to how `OnTriggerEnter` is supposed to work but here is my situation and how it differs from what I would expect.

I've created a very simple test project with a single scene. I have three objects in my scene - a player, an enemy, and an attack. The enemy and player both have rigid bodies and box colliders, neither of which is a trigger. The attack object has a box collider that IS a trigger. For scripts, the player has a script with nothing in it other than an `OnTriggerEnter` function that logs info to the console. The enemy has a simple script that just enables and disables the attack object in a cyclic pattern. When the attack is enabled it collides with the player.

Github with cloneable project/code: https://github.com/valevalorin/TriggerTest

**What I would expect to happen:**

The attack object is enabled and collides with the player. No console output is logged. The player object does not have a trigger collider on it so it's `OnTriggerEnter` should never be called.

**What actually happens:**

When the attack object collides with the  player, the player's `OnTriggerEnter` function gets called and output is logged to the console.

As far as I can tell, `OnTriggerEnter` should only be called on objects that actually have a trigger associated to them. Is this not how `OnTriggerEnter` works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html):

> Description
>
> OnTriggerEnter is called when the Collider other enters the trigger.
>
> This message is sent to the trigger collider **and the rigidbody (or the collider if there is no rigidbody) that touches the trigger.**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Thanks! I feel like an idiot not checking the documentation for this - it just felt so weird that I thought maybe my setup was wrong/weird/wonky in some way.

Comment: @Valevalorin No problem